# Clone TFS build definition in Visual Studio 2012/2013/2015?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2012

Steps in In Visual Studio 2010

- Open Team Explorer
- Go to Builds
- Right-click on a build definition, and click Clone.

How can I copy/clone a build in Visual Studio 2012? The Clone operation seems to be gone?

Note: I am using TFS 2010

Comment: Don't have the reputation to comment, but thought this might help someone... Use the VS2015 version (referenced in the accepted answer) to connect VS 2015 to TFS 2013 (12.0). It just worked for me.

Comment: Do you have the TFS power tools installed? If yes, that explains why it would work. If no, that's a pleasant surprise :)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Cloning build definition is a feature that comes with TFS Power Tools.

I haven't tried it but it seems to be part of the beta version for 2012 available here: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f

(updated url to published version. Thanks Bernard Vander Beken)

---

Visual Studio 2013 version:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f
(Credit to Bernard Vander Beken)

---

Visual Studio 2015 version:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1
(Credit to Bernard Vander Beken)

Comment: I need this exact functionality, and the link above now brings up a page that says this item hasn't been published. Was a non-beta version released or has the content been moved? I can't seem to find it...

Comment: Download URL for Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2012 Power Tools: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1ef7eb2-e084-4cb8-9bc7-06c3bad9148f

Comment: Download URL for Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2013 Power Tools
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f

Comment: Bug: in 2013, the right-click option for cloning currently doesn't appear if your Builds window is detached from the Team Explorer window.

Comment: Does anyone know what TFS PowerTools version I should select for the combination of VS2013 and TFS2010?

Comment: @MikeAsdf did you report the bug on the Power Tools page?

Comment: @alimbada Looks like they're currently aware of it: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f "Note: Some of the enhancments (such as the clone build definition) only work when its pane is docked. If you have undocked it (and became its own tool window), first dock it into Team Explorer. You can safely undock the pane again when you have completed the command"

Comment: Download URL for Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1